# Mongodb/Nested transactions : open transaction in another one not working

Tags: mongodb, transactions, nested, rollback

I am using MongoDb 4.2 in my web server.
When I open an session/transaction T2 inside a global session/transaction (T1), the commit within the T2 will persist in the database and  cannot be canceled in the global transaction T1.

How could we implement this nested transaction ?
Should I open only one singleton session in my web server and use it in all updating operations ?

Here is a example :

```
def remove_order_in_book(self, book, order):
        with self.start_session() as session:
            with session.start_transaction():
                book_collection.delete_one(..)

def remove_book_from_order(self, book):
   with client.start_session() as session:
         with session.start_transaction():
             orders = self.get_orders_of_book (book)
             for order in orders:
                self.remove_order_in_book(book, order)
```

Thank you for any idea !

Answer (score 3):

MongoDB [Transactions](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/transactions/) are associated with a session; At any given time, you can have at most *one* open transaction for a session.

Looking at your example, you should try to package all of the book order removal in one transaction. You can even use [collection.deleteMany()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.deleteMany/) in a transaction.

Also worth noting, that if a session ends and it has an open transaction, the transaction aborts.

Comment: Bachtiar, let me give another example where I need to implement a nested transaction: in your unit test, you would want to test a function which will update something in Mongodb within its  own transactions. At the end of the unit test, you would want certainly to rollback all the commit done in the tested function to preserve your test data. How could you do it with the transaction/session of Mongodb ? In a relational database, what I am doing is to open a global transaction which can be canceled any intermediate commits. Thanks!